# ButtonField click event

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm

i am not implementing touch event. i am using FieldChangeListener the problem which i am facing is , if i am clicking outside the CustomButtonField then also the click event is generated how should i restrict only to the CustomButtonField.

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

The listener will be invoked on all *change events* but you also get the field that changed (in the [fieldChanged](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/ui/FieldChangeListener.html#fieldChanged(net.rim.device.api.ui.Field,%20int)) function), so why not use that to make sure it is your field that was "changed"?

Comment: yes i have checked the buttonfield in the fieldChanged but its not working

Comment: What do you mean? You get the click event and it is the wrong field?

Comment: If i am clicking any where on the screen, the button which is focused is getting clicked

Comment: I think I understand the problem now... On the Storm, when your field is highlighted but the user clicks _outside_ your field, you still get the click event? Is that correct? So you button action gets executed as if it was clicked when in fact the click should have gone elsewhere?